# Can I save an Apache environment variable value with SetEnv?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, tomcat6

I am running Apache 2.2 with Tomcat 6 and have several layers of URL rewriting going on in both Apache with RewriteRule and in Tomcat. I want to pass through the original REQUEST_URI that Apache sees so that I can log it properly for "page not found" errors etc.

In httpd.conf I have a line:

```
SetEnv ORIG_URL %{REQUEST_URI}
```

and in the mod_jk.conf, I have:

```
JkEnvVar ORIG_URL
```

Which i thought should make the value available via `request.getAttribute("ORIG_URL")` in Servlets.

However, all that I see is `"%{REQUEST_URI}"`, so I assume that SetEnv doesn't interpret the `%{...}` syntax. What is the right way to get the URL the user requested in Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=ORIG_URL:$1]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! That did the trick. I added this as the first of the `RewriteRule`s and now `request.getAttribute("ORIG_URL")` gets the value!

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell Hey, I'm glad it worked and thanks for teaching me about using `JkEnvVar ORIG_URL` to set servlet attributes - v. useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getRequestURI()` and `getRequestURL()` (and perhaps the `getQueryString()`) methods of the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) class.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work since Apache has already manipulated the URL before passing it to Tomcat. So if my Apache rules change `/node/blah` to `/node.jsp?id=blah`, then `getRequestURI` sees the `/node.jsp` version.